# Power BI DAX Dynamic Calendar

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to create a Dynamic Table in Power BI.

I have my set of data, and basically I want the calendar to pick up the minimum date and the maximum date from my table, but only if the maximum date is not the month of today. If the maximum date is the month of today, then it should ignore it and the calendar should be created with the max date of the previous month.

I started the formula, but can't seem to continue it. Any ideas?

Calendar_= CALENDAR(MIN('Table1'[Date]),IF(MONTH(MAX('Table1'[Date]))=MONTH(TODAY()),date(YEAR(MAX('Table1'[Date])),.....

Answer (score 0):

See if this post helps: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Dynamic-table-or-on-fly-table-generation-via-DAX/m-p/434397#M200275. If not, I would simplify by creating some additional calculated columns or measures and then reference those instead of one nice big formula